# My App is asking for plenty url's with CanOpenUrl

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a problem with my Application, it always shows me that code in console when i'm trying to build my app.

```
 2015-10-30 15:24:36.673 MyApp[578:53278] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: 
 "fb206891282674529:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fb206891282674529"
    2015-10-30 15:24:36.675 MyApp[578:53278] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb439505206066620:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fb439505206066620"
    2015-10-30 15:24:36.676 MyApp[578:53278] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "ayi:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme ayi"
    2015-10-30 15:24:36.677 MyApp[578:53278] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "bikerace:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme bikerace"
    2015-10-30 15:24:36.679 MyApp[578:53278] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "db-lqycrgwnyt23sgf:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme db-lqycrgwnyt23sgf"
    2015-10-30 15:24:36.681 MyApp[578:53278] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "hulu:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme hulu"
    2015-10-30 15:24:36.684 MyApp[578:53278] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "skout:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme skout"
    2015-10-30 15:24:36.686 MyApp[578:53278] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "abcplayer:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme abcplayer"
    2015-10-30 15:24:36.688 MyApp[578:53278] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "dg028:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme dg028"
    2015-10-30 15:24:36.689 MyApp[578:53278] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "ilsgt:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme ilsgt"
    2015-10-30 15:24:36.690 MyApp[578:53278] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "gpappsptrackerlite:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme gpappsptrackerlite"
    2015-10-30 15:24:36.691 MyApp[578:53278] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "cupcake:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme cupcake"
    2015-10-30 15:24:36.693 MyApp[578:53278] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb179837925402275:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme fb179837925402275"
    2015-10-30 15:24:36.694 MyApp[578:53278] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "tocastore:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme tocastore"
```

and many other...
I don't have these applications on my iPhone. I've reinstalled my OS X and iOS in the phone.
I've searched the net about this problem, and I'm still confused with it. Here's a list of my CocoaPods installed:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod "AFNetworking", '< 2.1'
pod "YandexMobileMetrica", '~>1.6.2'
pod "iOS-Slide-Menu"
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
pod "FSOAuth", ‘< 1.2’
#pod 'AF2OAuth1Client', :git => 'https://github.com/joelchen/AFOAuth1Client.git'
pod 'JBChartView'
pod 'CCBottomRefreshControl'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

Somebody knows what to do?

Comment: Is YandexMobileMetrica the pod looking for installed apps?

Comment: @Raymond Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `canOpenURL:` is no longer permitted in iOS 9 without whitelisting in the *Info.plist*.

Comment: See this article: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/querying-url-schemes-with-canopenurl.html

Comment: Why not use the debugger and find out? You are not going to find out by asking _us_. You have a wonderful debugger. Debug!

Comment: Use. The. Debugger! Don't search. Set a symbolic breakpoint on `canOpenURL:`.

Comment: You're obviously wrong about that. Someone is calling it. A symbolic breakpoint will tell you who it is. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some of the libraries you use attempt to use `UIApplication canOpenURL:`. As of iOS 9.0 you need to add entries for each URL scheme in your Info.plist. The addition would look something like this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb439505206066620</string>
    <string>ayi</string>
</array>
```

Add a line for each scheme you see in the log. Do not include the colon in the scheme name.

Please note that even with these entries, if you don't have the corresponding app installed for one or more of these schemes, you will see a slightly different error message. They can safely be ignored.

In fact, you don't need to add all of these. Though depending on the library and how it makes use of a given scheme, the library could fail to work properly.